# Turtle graphics plotting

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics

when I plot a list of data(freqList):

> [0.09090909090909091, 0.0, 0.0, 0.09090909090909091, 0.18181818181818182, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.045454545454545456, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.045454545454545456, 0.045454545454545456, 0.045454545454545456, 0.045454545454545456, 0.18181818181818182, 0.045454545454545456, 0.09090909090909091, 0.045454545454545456, 0.0, 0.045454545454545456, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

When I try to fill in the bar with color, only half of the bar gets filled, resembling a right triangle. Also I can't figure out how to label the x and y- axis to have the letters a-z on the x axis representing each decimal. And the frequency from 0.0 - max(freqList) on the y - axis that increments up based on each decimal number. I know I have to use t.write(), but I don't know where to place it

```
def letterFreqPlot(freqList):

    border = 5
    t = turtle.Turtle()
    t.pensize(3)
    screen = t.getscreen()
    maxheight = max(freqList)
    numbers = len(freqList)
    screen.setworldcoordinates(0-border,-.05,numbers+1,maxheight)
    t.goto(0,0)
    t.speed(0)
    t.lt(90)
    t.fd(maxheight)
    t.fd(-maxheight)
    t.right(90)
    for item in freqList:
        t.fillcolor("blue")        
        for dist in [1, item, 1, item]:
            t.begin_fill()            
            t.fd(dist)
            t.lt(90)
        t.fd(1)
        t.end_fill()
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're making four `begin_fill` calls for every `end_fill` call. Try moving the begin call outside of the loop.

```
for item in freqList:
    t.fillcolor("blue")        
    t.begin_fill()            
    for dist in [1, item, 1, item]:
        t.fd(dist)
        t.lt(90)
    t.fd(1)
    t.end_fill()
```